# Generate a stock position report as at each month with a date variable set at a specific month

Tags: sql-server, date, while-loop

I am trying to generate a stock position report as at each month. within my query i have a date variable set at a specific month:

```
declare @date datetime = CONVERT(DATETIME, '2019-08-13 00:00:00', 121)
declare @lastmonth datetime = (select cast(dateadd(day, -day(getdate()), getdate()) as date))
declare  @m int = 0

--**my aim is to ensure that @date = @lastmonth** 
while @date<= @lastmonth
  Begin
     set @m = @m + 1
        while @m < 12
         Begin
    set @date = (select dateadd(mm, @m, @date))
      End
End

select
```

Comment: SQL is a set-based language. You don't need loops. You didn't ask a question though, or shown anything related to a stock position report. Just a loop

Comment: What is your question here?

Comment: If you want to group rows by month, the quick & dirty & slow solution would be to use `GROUP BY MONTH(someDateField)`. A better solution is to join to a [Calendar](https://www.sqlshack.com/designing-a-calendar-table/) table that contains date, year, month, fiscal period, and other similar fields for eg the next 50 years. This way, all you have to do is group by the periods you want in your report.

Comment: I have a date variable passed into my main query. I want to loop the dates incrementally which is then fed into my query. But my loop since to be an infinity loop

Comment: @Ade_1 that's not a question. That's a description of what that loop does, which you *don't* need. We've already seen the loop code. What you need is to fix the query so it works by month. Where is the query?

Comment: *"I want to loop the dates incrementally which is then fed into my query. But my loop since to be an infinity loop "* Don't loop; you're writing SQL, not C#.